# What do the arguments mean for Int 10h, AH 6h/7h?

Tags: assembly, x86, bios, vga

Kind of a dumb question, but nevertheless, can anyone explain to me what purpose do the registers cx and dx have in Int 10h with ah=6/7 (they both use the same variables just have scroll in different directions).

Everywhere I've looked it just says something similar to this:

> CH = Upper row number, CL = Left column number, DH = Lower row number, DL = Right column number

This doesn't really mean a lot to me, can anyone explain this in a way someone dumb like me can understand?

Comment: You can scroll a window (a rectangular part of the screen). You specify that window by those coordinates. Just go ahead and try it :)

Answer (score 10):

Consider this eye-stabbing psychedelic picture of a red rectangular window painted in ol' text mode:

[image: Rectangular red window]

Each white-blue square represents a character cell. Cells are counter top-right and **top-bottom**.
The numbers on the top, read downward, give a cell distance from the left edge<sup>1</sup>.
The numbers on the left give a cell distance from the top.

The pair *(distance from left, distance from top)*, unique for each cell<sup>2</sup>, is called the *coordinate pairs* or simply the *coordinates* (or even the *coords*).
It's customary to call the distance from left as *X* and the distance from top as *Y* and everything related to width as *something-X* and everything related to height as *something-Y*.

The big red rectangle is a window<sup>3</sup>.
Windows have two dimensions and a position. So a window can be identified with a triple *(position coord of top-left corner, size-X, size-Y)*.
For example the red window can be described as *((30, 8), 22, 7)* since it starts at *(30, 8)*, it's 22 cells wide and 7 cells tall.

Another way to describe a window is with the coords of the top-left corner and the coords of the bottom-right corner.
In this case the red window is *((30, 8), (51, 14))*.

---

The service `int 10h/AH=06h` can be used to move the **content inside** the red window up.
We need to tell it where window to move is, and since it uses the second notation, so we do.

`CL` and `CH` form the pair holding the top-left coords, X in *CL*, Y in *CH*.
`DL` and `DH` form the pair holding the bottom-right coords, X in *DL*, Y in *DH*.

This code, loads the registers properly (both versions equivalent)

```
;Easy version             ;Normal version
mov cl, 30                mov cx, 081eh
mov ch, 8                 mov dx, 0e34h
mov dl, 52
mov dh, 14
```

The other inputs of the service routines are trivial, but for `BH` which for now we set to zero.
Lets call the service:

```
mov ax, 0603h      ;Scroll three lines up
xor bh, bh
mov cx, 081eh
mov dx, 0e34h
int 10h
```

The result is:

[image: Window scrolled]

We can see that the **content inside** the window has been scrolled up by three lines.
Nothing outside the window has been touched.

We also note that the lines "shifted" in from below are black lines.
This is where the input `BH` comes into play, it contains the attribute (combination of color and background color) used to draw those lines.

For example the attribute *0e0h* specifies a bright yellow<sup>4</sup>, lets use it.

```
mov ax, 0603h      ;Scroll three lines up
mov bh, 0e0h       ;Yellow lines
mov cx, 081eh
mov dx, 0e34h
int 10h
```

[image: Window scrolled up with yellow lines]

Finally, the value of `AL` can be zero to scroll up the whole window, i.e. a number of lines equal to the height of the window.

---

For the service `int 10h/AH=07h` the rationale is the same but the window is scrolled **down**.

---

<sup>1</sup> In cell units.
<sup>2</sup> Note that the cells used to display the number have coordinates too.
<sup>3</sup> Because it actually looks like a window.
<sup>4</sup> Since we have the high intensity bit set in this context.

Comment: Great answer. Must have taken quite some time to write.

Comment: Ok, I understand how to use this now. I need this prompt in order to clear my screen of text. However, when I use it, the cursor disappears and when  I try to print strings they don't show up on the screen. Do you know how to fix it? I've tried int 10 ah 2 with dh and dl set as 0 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Hadarsi320 I think I'm not understanding what you are asking. If you have a follow up question, post it as such (i.e. as a new question), with all the relevant information and proper formatting. That would help in answering.

Answer (score 1):

The 16-bit register CX can be divided into two 8-bit halves, which are referred to as CL and CH. CL is the lower 8 bits (think of the mnemonic as being CL<sub>ow</sub>), while CH is the upper 8 bits (CH<sub>igh</sub>).
The same is true for the DX register: the lower 8 bits are in DL, and the upper 8 bits are in DH.

Indeed, all 4 of the x86's primary general-purpose registers—EAX, EDX, ECX, and EBX—have 8-bit and 16-bit overlapping aliases:

```
------------------------------------
|               EAX                |    (32 bits)
-----------------------------------
                 |       AX        |    (16 bits)
                 -------------------
                 |   AH   |   AL   |    (8 bits)
                 -------------------
```

So, the documentation for the int 10h function is telling you that the lower 8 bits of CX (CL) contains the left-most column of the window, while the upper 8 bits of CX (CH) contains the top-most row of the window. The lower 8 bits of DX (DL) contains the right-most column of the window, while the upper 8 bits of DX (DH) contains the bottom-most row of the window.

In other words, you are passing the function values that describe a *rectangle* in terms of its left, top, right, and bottom bounds. CX contains two 8-bit values that specify the window's top-left coordinate, while DX contains two 8-bit values that specify the window's bottom-right coordinate.

(When I say "window" here, I mean "rectangular area on the screen to be scrolled".)